# .animate only working 1 way

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am using jquery animate to open & close a sidebar, it works fine when opening the sidebar, but does not work when closing it

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
 $("#sidebar_open").bind("click", function(){
     var $inner = $("#sidebar");
     $inner.stop().animate({width:'200px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'swing'});
  $(".nav-btn").html('<center><img id="sidebar_close" src="images/arrow_left.png" width="30" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;"></center>');
 });
 $("#sidebar_close").bind("click", function(){
     var $inner = $("#sidebar");
     $inner.stop().animate({width:'62px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'swing'});
  $(".nav-btn").html('<center><img id="sidebar_open" src="images/arrow_right.png" width="30" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;"></center>');
 });
});
```

```css
div#sidebar {
 width:62px;
 position:fixed;
 height:87%;
 left:0;
 background:#42515f; 
 top:96px;
 padding-top:3%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/dashboard_icon.png" width="18"> Dashboard</a>
    <div class="nav-btn" style="width:100%; float:left; margin-top:50px;"><center><img id="sidebar_open" src="images/arrow_right.png" width="30" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;"></center></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are replacing the `img` dynamically you need to use [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("#sidebar").on("click", '#sidebar_open',function () {
```

and

```
$("#sidebar").on("click", '#sidebar_close',function () {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13968hrs/)**

---

Another way would be to use condition in one function:

```
$("#sidebar").on("click", '#sidebar_img', function () {

    var $inner = $("#sidebar");
    var sidebarWidth;
    var src;
    if ($inner.hasClass('sidebar_closed')) {
        sidebarWidth = '200px';
        src = 'images/arrow_left.png';
    } else {
        sidebarWidth = '62px';
        src = 'images/arrow_right.png';
    }
    $inner.stop().animate({
        width: sidebarWidth
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'swing',
        complete: function () {
            $inner.toggleClass('sidebar_open sidebar_closed');
            $('#sidebar_img').attr('src', src);
        }
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/of6qrq6j/)**

Comment: Ace Mate! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanBaker glad I could help you, If you want to, have a look at my second example

Comment: is there a way to make to the img rotates 180* as the sidebar slides?

Comment: Thanks @empiric, i realised what i had done in error thanks to your demo, appreciate the help!